# Having trouble converting a d3d9 pixelshader to d3d11

Tags: shader, hlsl, direct3d, direct3d11, pixel-shader

I've got this pixel shader that I'm trying to convert. I've corrected all the syntax for d3d11 but when I run the HLSL file through the compiler that spits out the .fxc file, it gives me this error:

```
warning X3206: 'dot': implicit truncation of vector type
```

Note that I am not well versed in this stuff at all.

Here's the code.

```html
// Global variables
Texture2D<float4> img;
sampler imgSampler;

Texture2D<float4> bkd : register(t1);
sampler bkdSampler : register(s1);

cbuffer PS_VARIABLES : register(b0)
{
int lightAenabled, lightBenabled, lightCenabled;
float4 lightAColor, lightBColor, lightCColor, ambientLight;
float lightAX, lightBX, lightCX;
float lightAY, lightBY, lightCY;
float lightAZ, lightBZ, lightCZ;
float lightABrightness, lightBBrightness, lightCBrightness;
float objX, objY;

};

cbuffer PS_PIXELSIZE : register(b1)
{
float fPixelWidth;
float fPixelHeight;
};


float4 ps_main(in float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD ) : SV_TARGET
{
    float4 normal = img.Sample(imgSampler, texCoord);
    normal = float4(normal.x - 0.5, normal.y - 0.5, normal.z - 0.5, normal.w);
    float4 background = bkd.Sample(bkdSampler, texCoord);
    float4 color = float4(0,0,0,normal.a);
    float3 pixelPos = float3(texCoord.xy,0);
    float3 objPos = float3(objX,objY,0);
    float3 lightPos;
    float3 dir;
    float dist, amount;
    
    

    if(lightAenabled)
    {
        
        lightPos = float3((lightAX-objX)*fPixelWidth+0.5,(lightAY-objY)*fPixelHeight+0.5,lightAZ);
        dir = normalize(lightPos - pixelPos);
        dist = 1/length(lightPos - pixelPos);
        float3 amount = (normal, dir);
        color.rgb += amount * lightABrightness * dist * lightAColor.rgb;
    }
    
    if(lightBenabled)
    {
        lightPos = float3((lightBX-objX)*fPixelWidth+0.5,(lightBY-objY)*fPixelHeight+0.5,lightBZ);
        dir = normalize(lightPos - pixelPos);
        dist = 1/length(lightPos - pixelPos);
         amount = saturate(dot(normal,dir));
        color.rgb += amount * lightBBrightness * dist * lightBColor.rgb;
    }
    
    if(lightCenabled)
    {
        lightPos = float3((lightCX-objX)*fPixelWidth+0.5,(lightCY-objY)*fPixelHeight+0.5,lightCZ);
        dir = normalize(lightPos - pixelPos);
        dist = 1/length(lightPos - pixelPos);
        amount = saturate(dot(normal,dir));
        color.rgb += amount * lightCBrightness * dist * lightCColor.rgb;
    }

    return float4(ambientLight.rgb,0) + color * background;
};



float4 Demultiply(float4 _color)
{
float4 color = _color;
    if ( color.a != 0 )
        color.rgb /= color.a;
    return color;
}



float4 ps_main_pm(in float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD ) : SV_TARGET
{
    float4 normal = Demultiply(img.Sample(imgSampler, texCoord));
    normal = float4(normal.x-0.5, normal.y-0.5, normal.z-0.5, normal.w);
    float4 background = Demultiply(bkd.Sample(bkdSampler, texCoord));
    float4 color = float4(0,0,0,normal.a);
    float4 O = float4(ambientLight.rgb, 0) + color * background;
    float3 pixelPos = float3(texCoord.xy,0);
    float3 objPos = float3(objX,objY,0);
    float3 lightPos, dir;
    float dist, amount; 
    


    if(lightAenabled)
    {
        lightPos = float3((lightAX-objX)*fPixelWidth+0.5,(lightAY-objY)*fPixelHeight+0.5,lightAZ);
        dir = normalize(lightPos - pixelPos);
        dist = 1/length(lightPos - pixelPos);
        amount = saturate(dot(normal,dir));
        color.rgb += amount * lightABrightness * dist * lightAColor.rgb;
    }
    
    if(lightBenabled)
    {
        lightPos = float3((lightBX-objX)*fPixelWidth+0.5,(lightBY-objY)*fPixelHeight+0.5,lightBZ);
        dir = normalize(lightPos - pixelPos);
        dist = 1/length(lightPos - pixelPos);
        amount = saturate(dot(normal,dir));
        color.rgb += amount * lightBBrightness * dist * lightBColor.rgb;
    }
    
    if(lightCenabled)
    {
        lightPos = float3((lightCX-objX)*fPixelWidth+0.5,(lightCY-objY)*fPixelHeight+0.5,lightCZ);
        dir = normalize(lightPos - pixelPos);
        dist = 1/length(lightPos - pixelPos);
        amount = saturate(dot(normal,dir));
        color.rgb += amount * lightCBrightness * dist * lightCColor.rgb;
    }

    O.rgb *= O;
    return O;
    
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The `normal` is a 4-vector. The `dir` is a 3-vector. The *dot-product* is only valid for vectors of the same length.

In this case `normal.a` is some other value in the 'normal texture', so you can just use source-register masking/swizzling to convert it to a 3-vector, which is what is happening implicitly:

```
amount = saturate(dot(normal.xyz,dir));
```

> `normal.rgb` and `normal.xyz` would do the same thing.

Comment: Ahh alright thank you. Now the compiler spits out the fxc without any errors, but the shader is just completely black now. Would you happen to know why that is? I can post the original d3d9 code if needed.

Comment: Graphics debugging is challenging. Any number of bugs can result in a black screen. The best advice I can give you is to build up from a working case and add one thing at a time. Make sure you have the [debug device](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/) enabled, and check all ``HRESULT`` return values for success/failure. You may also want to take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit for DX11](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).